# typescript error on nested object with string keys: TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following interface:

```
type HasuraClaim = {
  'x-hasura-default-role': string;
  'x-hasura-user-id': string;
  'x-hasura-allowed-roles': string[];
};

export interface IdToken {
  family_name: string;
  given_name: string;
  name: string;
  'https://hasura.io/jwt/claims': HasuraClaim;
  sub: string;
  <...more here...>
}
```

When I access it as follows:

```
const role = idToken['https://hasura.io/jwt/claims']['x-hasura-default-role']
```

I receive the following error and `['x-hasura-default-role']` is underlined:

**TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.**

How can I change my typing so typescript will not warn? I have not found a similar question with nested string keys.

EDIT: I found I could do the following without problems:

```
const claims = idToken['https://hasura.io/jwt/claims'];
const role = claims['x-hasura-default-role'];
```

Comment: Not reproducible. Which version of typescript do you use?  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwK4Cc4GEA2cCWBbKAXigG8AoKKAcgA8BaAC0VTjoBMIAzOJTYOlAHtMEKgC4oCYChwA7AOYBuCtXpNkaOkgQQUdHG3GTpcpStqNmmuJkyCA7hDYDhEBEakyFAbQC6ygF9lMggaMEEUYCg5YF1uAGNoAEk2ABVBAGsIWVIVbjwcTBAAfVk4PAgJT1NlSnkcADds0vLK4y8zSjKKqpMFWuoGYGAwBDEAenH1FgA6HEFxgCt7YHH47Hx3CXgNDA28AeQAI16OwLIyDnW4FGh4wVkpaLTM7IkU9KzZZXvHqKERERnp9st4qEMRmNJtM0HMFstVtdNlRfGC1FZWBxuLx+ADRL4gA

Comment: I use typescript 3.8.3

Comment: We're missing some context here, can you show us how you declare the `idToken` variable?

Comment: Works in 3.8.3 as expected https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.8.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwK4Cc4GEA2cCWBbKAXigG8AoKKAcgA8BaAC0VTjoBMIAzOJTYOlAHtMEKgC4oCYChwA7AOYBuCtXpNkaOkgQQUdHG3GTpcpStqNmmuJkyCA7hDYDhEBEakyFAbQC6ygF9lMggaMEEUYCg5YF1uAGNoAEk2ABVBAGsIWVIVbjwcTBAAfVk4PAgJT1NlSnkcADds0vLK4y8zSjKKqpMFWuoGYGAwBDEAenH1FgA6HEFxgCt7YHH47Hx3CXgNDA28AeQAI16OwLIyDnW4FGh4wVkpaLTM7IkU9KzZZXvHqKERERnp9st4qEMRmNJtM0HMFstVtdNlRfGC1FZWBxuLx+ADRL4gA

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be at your declaration. You need `idToken` to be inferred as `IdToken`.

```js
const idToken: IdToken = { ... }
```